# flex mobile login system with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, mobile

I tried to build a flex mobile login system with php and mysql , i used the  to connect with the login  php script and i made the necessary server configuration for the project.Here is the http service tag that i used :

```
<s:HTTPService id="login_user" url="mylogin.php" method="post" useProxy="false" result="onResult(event)"   >
        <s:request xmlns="">
        <first_name>
            {first_name.text}
        </first_name>
        <password>
            {password.text}
        </password> 
        </s:request>    

        </s:HTTPService>
```

but i got the following error :

> [RPC Fault faultString="HTTP request error"
>   faultCode="Server.Error.Request" faultDetail="Error: [IOErrorEvent
>   type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: app:/yourlogin.php" errorID=2032]. URL: login.php"]

I can't understand what's wrong , can you help me please ?

Comment: Does this help: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Flex_Error__2032__Stream_Error-17265.html .  Are you sure that your URL is correct?

Comment: yes , i'm sure the url is correct, the problem is that i can't understand the errors that i got

Comment: I wonder if working with a remote database in flex mobile is the same thing as working with remote database in flex for web application ?

Comment: Flex really knows nothing about the database [theoretically].  But, working with a remote service in a Flex mobile is identical to working w/ a remote service in a web application, with the one exception that cross domain policies that apply to browser based applications do not apply to mobile applications.  That is not the issue here.  Reviewing the error again the URL is "app:/yourlogin.php".  I originall thought app related to the directory.  Wouldn't the protocol you need be HTTP?  And don't you need to specify an absolute URL in your code; with the full domain name?

Comment: the mylogin.php script that i use is in the www folder of the wamp folder installed in mylocal machine.All the flex similar examples for the web app version have a relative URL in the url attribute of their HTTPService tag.

Comment: Relative URLs work great when the app is served from the same web server as your service.  But, a mobile app is not served from a server; it is running 'native' to your device [or emulator].  The app won't know how to find your web server unless you tell it to by specifying the complete URL.

Comment: I tried to connect to localhost from my browser but the access is denied , i  think that's what is causing the errors with flex mobile and the database

Comment: Yes, if your local web server is setup incorrectly your mobile app will not be able to access it.

Comment: I have another question about flex mobile: it's about streaming the device 's live video  to a media server like flash media server.I tryed that once with a flex web application and it worked but i wonder if it will work with flex mobile using the same classes and methods(NetConnection and NetStream classes) ?

Comment: It should work the same; but streaming video isn't my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Try full path like `http://localhost/?yourPath?/mylogin.php`

```
<s:HTTPService id="login_user" url="http://localhost/?yourPath?/mylogin.php"
```